# MPLABX 5.40 MPASM Assembly PIC

Tags: assembly, pic, mplab

I would like to ask about your experience with MPLABX 5.40 supporting MPASM on a 64bit windows machine?

I can't see it in the listed compilers when creating a new project (I see only XC8 compiler). I've been crawling through forums for a dood portion of the day now and all I've found was this message for MPLABX 5.35:

> MPASM is not supported on 64 bit Operating Systems. Please consider migrating your project "Mk8B_MPLabX" configuration "default" to XC8 Assembler or continue to use a previously released IDE.

But at the time of writing the post the person was claming that the project would still compile and run.

**Is 5.40 the version where they've cut the lifeline of MPASM and there is nothing I can do about it?** It is difficult to find any official announcement from Microchip regarding this matter.

I've found out that I can use MPLAB 8.92 from 2011 which still supports MPASM and that it indeed works. Still, I would like to use the most up to date IDE if ppossible. I just wanted to be sure I'm not missing something obvious.

Microchip seems to heavily favor the C language over Assembly now; however, I need to use Assembly on an 8bit PIC microchip. No alternatives possible.

Thank you.

Comment: MPASM died with version 5.4 so you had to switch back to version 5.3.

Answer (score 3):

Microchip has not done the best job of integration with the pic-as tools chain.

For most user this means that they will need to manually integrate the pic-as tools chain with the MPLABX IDE.

To manually add a tool chain to MPLABX:
[image]

I installed XC8 on the path: C:\PIC_dev\MPLABXC\xc8\v2.20

Your path may be different.

See my git [repository](https://github.com/dsoze1138/MPLABXv540_pic-as_examples) for pic-as coding example projects that are complete and build. The code examples Microchip includes in their [XC8-PIC-Assembler-UG-for-EE-50002994A.pdf](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/XC8-PIC-Assembler-UG-for-EE-50002994A.pdf) document are hard to follow and in some cases too incomplete to build.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with Assembly on 8 Bit PIC you have got two choices:

1. Work with MPLAX 5.35 (and lower). MPASM is still integrated here.
2. If you want to work with MPLABX 5.4 (and up) you had to install the xc8 compiler manually and work with the PIC-Assembler, which comes with this compiler.

Please remember, there are several [differences](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MPASM%20to%20MPLAB%20XC8%20PIC%20Assembler%20Migration%20Guide%2050002973A.pdf) between both assembler.
e.g.

- configuration bits should be defined with the configdirective
- labels had to be defined with a :
- PSECT to define Data memory
- and so on...